# Image Name Problem when inserting into media gallery

Tags: android, image, insert, gallery

```
     MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), imageFile.getAbsolutePath(), imageFile.getName(), null);
```

when I insert my Image to gallery using above code..

it shows different name.

It takes Timestamp value as Image name....

Anyone knows why it happens?

Thanks